# Does compiler knows relocatable address of local variables

Tags: c, memory-management, local-variables, stack-memory

I have recently came across a text "Deep C Secrets" that discusses about compiler resolving variables at compile time. This is possible for global and static variables as they occupy space till the end of the program but what is the case with local variable which gets space on stack? Do they get space allocated at run time and if so how does compiler keep track of their addresses?

Answer (score 3):

Well, local vairables just work differently then global/static ones.

Local vairables are "allocated" on the stack, which in turn is a chunk of memory allocated by the system for your running program. There's a "pointer" held by the CPU that points into that stack, called the stack pointer, and some compiler/CPU "magic" updates that pointer on function calls.

In the end, the "stack pointer" sort of points to a local chunk of memory for every function call, like a piece of paper that's private for each function call so the function can use it to take notes that aren't visible elsewhere. Thus, the compiler doesn't really deal with "addresses" of local variables since these are determined at runtime -- instead, the compiler "keeps track" of the location of a local variable on that "piece of paper". In other words, the location of a local variable is "relative to the stack pointer", or kept as an "offset to the stack pointer"

Answer (score 0):

Their address is relative to the stack pointer (actually base pointer in most cases, IIRC), which is moved each time a function call is performed (except `inline` functions of course).

To read a local variable, the generated assembly will look like :

```
mov eax, [ebp -  4]
```

where `-4` is the position of the variable relative to `ebp` (the Extended (32-bit) Base Pointer). If you have two `int` variables (thus two 32-bit variables), their positions will be `-8` and `-4` (since 32-bits are 4 bytes wide on the X86 architecture).

When in doubt, the best thing to do is to write a short program, and compile it to assembly :

```
gcc -S program.c -o output.S
cat output.S
```

For more info on function calls at the assembly level, see [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames).

Comment: Deep C secrets was written by people developing the SunOS operating system. The generated assembly language would look extremely unlike that. On sun boxes, there's a frame pointer and a stack pointer, and mostly local variables are addressed relative to the frame pointer (but not always)

Comment: You can see how several processors use local memory by trying the ELLCC online demo: http://ellcc.org/demo

Comment: @Georges - I realise it's different nomenclature for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is an interesting question.  I'm speaking in general here, but this has been true as long as I can remember.  The secret is that the compiler, at compile time, forces all calling routines and all called routines to obey the same protocol.  That's what makes this all work.
The compiler puts out assy code so that the calling routine pushes the function parameters onto the stack (probably in the order they're listed).  Then the calling routine jumps to the called routine, leaving the return address (the statement after the function call) on the stack.

The compiler puts out similar assy code for the called routine so that it looks for these parameters on the stack, in the same order they were pushed.  When the called routine finishes using the parameters, it pops them off the stack; pops the return address off the stack (keeping it); pushes the answer (which is the function return type) onto the stack (where the calling routine will look for it), and then jumps to the return address.

The calling routine pops the answer off the stack and goes about using it.

The whole process for these function parameters is thus relocatable.

And by the way, all the 'local' variables (within the called function) also exist on the stack, but only for the time the called function is running.  The called function borrows that space temporarily (until it returns).  Only the function knows where those local variables are.  That is why the local variables are lost after the function returns.

Hope I got it all right.